# integrate push notifications for android with localytics

Tags: java, android, analytics, segments, localytics

Has anyone Integrated push notifications for Android using Localytics?

I have done code changes mentioned on their website.
[Localytics Android Integration](http://docs.localytics.com/#Dev/Integrate/android-automatic-integration.html)

Now when i am trying to configure my app with Google API key it is giving me error saying provide password for Push Notification:

> ErrorMessage: An error occurred. Possible cert password or validation issues. Please try again or contact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We encountered the same issue and resolved it by regenerating the GCM API key. To do so, you have to go to:

https://console.developers.google.com/project

Find the project in question. Go to Enabled APIs, find "Google Cloud Messaging", and disable the API key.

Then return to the GCM page:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue

And re-enable the project for GCM. The new API key generated by this process worked for us with Localytics.